# getElementByTagName() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  <pre> function whatImg(){
            var str = getUrlVars()["obj"];
            document.getElementByTagName('img').src = 'images/dog.png';
            }                                   
        function getUrlVars() {
            var vars = {};
            var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {vars[key] = value;});
            return vars;
        }<code>                             
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page">
        <img src="images/keys.png" id="image"/>
        <script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript">  whatImg();</script>     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is `getElementsByTagName` not `getElementByTagName`

and use `document.getElementByTagName('img')[0].src` instead

and you'd better write js code below the html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <img src="images/keys.png" id="image" />
        </div>
        <script>
            function whatImg() {
                var str = getUrlVars()["obj"];
                document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = 'images/dog.png';
            }

            function getUrlVars() {
                var vars = {};
                var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
                    vars[key] = value;
                });
                return vars;
            }
            whatImg();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW, the `language` attribute is obsolete in HTML5.

Comment: thanks it worked!!!! you are awsome!

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no such thing as `getElementByTagName`. You forgot an `s`: [`.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).

Also it returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList), which means you have to do this:

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
ele[0].src = 'images/dog.png';
```

Sometimes it might be better to get the element using `id`:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('image');
ele.src = 'images/dog.png';
```

Comment: you're right but still doesn't work :(

Comment: You missed the `s` in your example as well... From the example code, I think OP might be better off using `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @Blender - I am sure that there is an `s` in my example...

Comment: @Derek: Yep, now there is.

Answer (score 0):

That returns an `HTMLCollection`, so you have to loop over it and assign each `src` attribute that value.

Comment: can you explain it because i'm newbie? :/

Comment: @user2089586 Notice the "s" in `getElementsByTagName` ? That means there is the possibility that there could be more than 1 element returned, so you get a list even if there's just one element returned. So, you need to use a `for` or `while` loop to go through that list and set each element's `src` property equal to 'images/dog.png'

Comment: @user2089586 ECMAScript says it's supposed to be a `NodeList`, like Derek said, but only modern WebKit browsers actually return a NodeList. Firefox calls it an `HTMLCollection`